# Update mySQL field with variable number of other fields

Tags: mysql, sql-update, parent-child, concatenation

i have a mySQL table set up like this

```
+----+----------+---------+
| id | parentid | content |
+----+----------+---------+
| 1  | 0        | a       |
| 2  | 1        | b       |
| 3  | 0        | c       |
| 4  | 3        | d       |
| 5  | 3        | e       |
| 6  | 3        | f       |
+----+----------+---------+
```

what i would like to do is concatenate the content of the children onto the end of the parent (then delete the children, but i will do that later), in ASC order based on id.  so the result should look like this (without children)

```
+----+----------+---------+
| id | parentid | content |
+----+----------+---------+
| 1  | 0        | ab      |
| 3  | 0        | cdef    |    
+----+----------+---------+
```

the issue im running into is that as you can see a parent may have more than one child.  so far the query i have is

```
UPDATE table 
SET content = CONCAT(content, 
...
) ORDER BY id ASC
```

im not sure what to place in the `...` section to grab all of the children and append them in order they were retrieved.  maybe im going about it the wrong way.   any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is:

```sql
/*Table structure for table `table` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table`;

CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parentid` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `content` VARCHAR(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

/*Data for the table `table` */

INSERT  INTO `table`(`parentid`,`content`)
VALUES
(0,'a'),(1,'b'),(0,'c'),(3,'d'),(3,'e'),(3,'f');

UPDATE `table`
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT `t0`.`id`, CONCAT(`t0`.`content`, GROUP_CONCAT(`t1`.`content` SEPARATOR '')) AS `content`
     FROM `table` `t0`
        INNER JOIN `table` `t1` ON `t0`.`id` = `t1`.`parentid`
     WHERE `t0`.`parentid` = 0
     GROUP BY `t1`.`parentid`) `der`
SET `table`.`content` = `der`.`content`
WHERE `table`.`id` = `der`.`id`;

DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `parentid` > 0;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12b0f/1)</kbd>

Comment: thank you this seems to work except that some of the content seems to be getting chopped off.  The group_concat works, but it looks like the number of characters that can be concatenated is being limited...any ideas?

Comment: nvm, just found this, [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: awesome, after setting group_concat_max_len = 10000000, and changing `WHERE t0.parentid = 0` to `WHERE t1.parentid > 0` it worked perfectly.  My example was a little different then the real DB so thats what that one change was for.  thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You have to perfom so much changes to the table that it might be better to create another one with the new data and drop the current one.

The query that will get you the results you're looking for is:

```
SELECT
  min(t1.id) id,
  0 parentid,
  group_concat(t1.content ORDER BY t1.id separator '') content
FROM t t1
LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t1.parentid = t2.id
GROUP BY coalesce(t2.id, t1.id);
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7df6/1).